# Facebook API encoding issue

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, encoding

I'm implementing facebook login on my site and the auth process works fine, but there is another problem. When I try to get the name of the user from the auth response, I'm getting this:

```
Array ( [name] => ÐÐ¸ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð°Ð¹ Ð”ÑÐ½ÐºÐ¾Ð² [image] => ...
```

This name is supposed to be in Cyrillic characters and I need to:

1. Display it to the user in cyrilic
2. Store it safely in database and be able to convert it back to cyrillic later

I tried using json_decode() and iconv() but no success. Maybe I can't get the parameters right. Please help!

Comment: Quite possibly it's your application's charset that's breaking it. You should only use UTF-8.

Comment: @Narf can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I can't be more specific than 'use only UTF-8'. :)

Comment: @Narf Maybe he needs example of direct implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use header to modify the HTTP header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Place it at the top of your php file or at a common file which you include everywhere, such as config file.